# Python assert with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, assert

I ran into a unique issue while writing test cases with `pytest`
If we write a test as:-

```
a = 4
b = 5
c = 4

def match_test():
    assert a == (b or c) # (fails with `AssertionError`)
```

Now if we do the same using constants

```
def match_test():
    assert a == (4 or 5)  (passes)
```

But passes if we breakdown the assert as:-

```
def match_test():
    assert a == b or a == c # (passed)
```

The same happens with strings, curious if anyone can explain why this unique behaviour, PS I am new to `Pytest` and `assert` statements.

Comment: The condition `a == (4 or 5)` probably passed when you tried it because `a` was 4. The code you wrote is equivalent to `a == 4`, and it is not a correct way to use `or`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Yes, I accepted this as duplicate, I thought this is unique to assert statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. `(4 or 5)` is evaluated to 4, so

```
assert a == (4 or 5)
```

passes since `4 == 4`.

`(b or c)` is evaluated to 5 (`b` is 5) so

```
assert a == (b or c)
```

fails since `4 != 5`. `assert a == (c or b)` will pass.

```
assert a == b or a == c
```

pass because the `assert` evaluates the entire expression, `True or False` is `True`.